# convert data frame from row per time period to one row per day

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm working with a data frame that holds locations of patients during a hospital admission. It is formatted in a way that each row represents a new location (=department, room, bed) over a certain time period (from BeginTim to EndTime) for that person (=ID).

Here's a sample of the initial data frame:

```
 print(data_perlocation[1:10,])
    ID      department      BeginTime                     EndTime             room   Bed
   <dbl>      <chr>            <chr>                       <chr>               <dbl> <dbl>
1 2156864       L14B 2016-03-02 09:40:00.0000000 2016-03-02 15:20:00.0000000   102     3
2 2161034       B51A 2016-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 2016-06-07 11:02:00.0000000   109     2
3 2161034       B51A 2016-06-06 09:00:00.0000000 2016-06-06 10:27:00.0000000   109     2
4 2161034       B51A 2016-06-06 12:47:00.0000000 2016-06-07 00:00:00.0000000   109     2
5 2161034       B51A 2016-06-06 10:27:00.0000000 2016-06-06 12:47:00.0000000   103     3
6 2176442       L14B 2016-02-04 07:15:00.0000000 2016-02-04 13:47:00.0000000   101     4
7 2176754       B61A 2016-03-15 07:16:00.0000000 2016-03-15 14:56:00.0000000   109     3
8 2176754       B61A 2016-03-16 08:10:00.0000000 2016-03-17 00:00:00.0000000   109     3
9 2176754       B61A 2016-03-15 14:56:00.0000000 2016-03-16 08:10:00.0000000   109     2
10 2176754      B61A 2016-03-17 00:00:00.0000000 2016-03-17 11:18:00.0000000   109     3
11 2184060      B61A 2016-03-10 20:25:00.0000000 2016-03-11 00:00:00.0000000   105     2
12 2184060      B61A 2016-03-10 20:01:00.0000000 2016-03-10 20:25:00.0000000   105     1
13 2184060      B61A 2016-03-11 00:00:00.0000000 2016-03-12 00:00:00.0000000   105     2
14 2184060      B61A 2016-03-12 00:00:00.0000000 2016-03-12 14:00:00.0000000   105     2
```

I want to convert this data frame so that I will have a row for each day. Therefore, I created a new data frame with column that hold the ID and day of admission. Like this:

```
    ID       Date
1  2156864 2016-03-02
2  2161034 2016-06-06
3  2161034 2016-06-07
4  2176442 2016-02-04
5  2176754 2016-03-15
6  2176754 2016-03-16
7  2176754 2016-03-17
8  2184060 2016-03-10
9  2184060 2016-03-11
10 2184060 2016-03-12
```

Now I want to add the (multiple) location(s) per day that are present in the `data_bylocation` data frame to the `data_byday` row with matching `ID` and where the `beginDate` matches Date.

I ended up combining a for and two if statements. My attempts so far have not been giving anything near a desired outcome and I think their must be a much easier way to do this. My last try ended up something like this:

```
data_perday[,3] <- NA
for (index in 1:nrow(data_perlocation)){
  if (data_perlocation$ID[index]==data_perday$ID & as.Date(as.character(data_perlocation$BeginTime[index]), format="%Y-%m-%d")==as.Date(data_perday$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")) {
    if (is.na(data_perday[index,3])){           
    ##code to assign location and time of for that day
} else {
    ##code to assign second location and time of for that day and place
      }}}
```

The desired outcome looks something like this:

```
    ID       Date        BeginTime1  EndTime1  department1  room1  bed1       BeginTime2  EndTime2  department2  room2  bed2   [3rd location, etc]
1  2156864 2016-03-02              [first location of this day]                      [second location of this day] 
2  2161034 2016-06-06
3  2161034 2016-06-07
4  2176442 2016-02-04
5  2176754 2016-03-15
6  2176754 2016-03-16
7  2176754 2016-03-17
8  2184060 2016-03-10
9  2184060 2016-03-11
10 2184060 2016-03-12
```

I'm quite new to R, still learning. I've been stuck with this problem for a while. So any tips in the right direction are much appreciated!

EDIT:

Reproducible examples:

```
data_byday <- structure(list(ID = c(2156864, 2161034, 2161034, 2176442, 2176754, 2176754, 2176754, 2184060, 2184060, 2184060), Date = c("2016-03-02", "2016-06-06", "2016-06-07", "2016-02-04", "2016-03-15", "2016-03-16", "2016-03-17", "2016-03-10", "2016-03-11", "2016-03-12")), .Names = c("ID", "Date"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")


data_bylocation <- structure(list(ID = c(2156864, 2161034, 2161034, 2161034, 2161034, 2176442, 2176754, 2176754, 2176754, 2176754, 2184060, 2184060, 2184060, 2184060), department = c("L14B", "B51A", "B51A", "B51A", "B51A", "L14B", "B61A", "B61A", "B61A", "B61A", "B61A", "B61A", "B61A", "B61A"), BeginTime = c("2016-03-02 09:40:00.0000000", "2016-06-07 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-06-06 09:00:00.0000000", "2016-06-06 12:47:00.0000000", "2016-06-06 10:27:00.0000000", "2016-02-04 07:15:00.0000000", "2016-03-15 07:16:00.0000000", "2016-03-16 08:10:00.0000000", "2016-03-15 14:56:00.0000000", "2016-03-17 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-03-10 20:25:00.0000000", "2016-03-10 20:01:00.0000000", "2016-03-11 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-03-12 00:00:00.0000000"), EndTime = c("2016-03-02 15:20:00.0000000", "2016-06-07 11:02:00.0000000", "2016-06-06 10:27:00.0000000", "2016-06-07 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-06-06 12:47:00.0000000", "2016-02-04 13:47:00.0000000", "2016-03-15 14:56:00.0000000", "2016-03-17 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-03-16 08:10:00.0000000", "2016-03-17 11:18:00.0000000", "2016-03-11 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-03-10 20:25:00.0000000", "2016-03-12 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-03-12 14:00:00.0000000"), room = c(102, 109, 109, 109, 103, 101, 109, 109, 109, 109, 105, 105, 105, 105), Bed = c(3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2)), .Names = c("ID", "department", "BeginTime", "EndTime", "room", "Bed"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Second example:

```
data_bylocation2 <- structure(list(ID = c(2224003, 2224003, 2224003, 2248787, 2248787,2248787, 2248787, 2248787), department = c("B12A", "B12A", "B12A","B53A", "B53A", "B53A", "B53A", "B53A"), BeginTime = c("2016-02-12 08:00:00.0000000", "2016-02-12 13:40:00.0000000", "2016-02-15 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-04-20 10:00:00.0000000", "2016-04-22 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-04-23 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-04-24 11:47:00.0000000", "2016-04-26 00:00:00.0000000"), EndTime = c("2016-02-12 13:40:00.0000000", "2016-02-15 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-02-15 16:17:00.0000000", "2016-04-22 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-04-23 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-04-24 11:47:00.0000000", "2016-04-26 00:00:00.0000000", "2016-04-26 16:00:00.0000000"), room = c(205, 209, 209, 306, 306, 306, 311, 311), bed = c(3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4)), .Names = c("ID", "department", "BeginTime", "EndTime", "room", "bed"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Why do you have months/days in your expected output that you don't have in your input?

Comment: Indeed, I posted two different samples from larger data frames. I edited the question so IDs are now matched for the samples.

Comment: looks like a one liner with data.tables dcast but I'm to lazy to copy your data myself: could you provide a reproducible example in the form of "data <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=11:20)" that I can just copy paste to check this? Alternatively, show the idea of the problem in "data <- iris" or another dataset implemented in R.

Comment: Does this (see edit) suffice as a reproducible example?

Comment: @PeterPan I'm interested to see how this can be done with a one-liner in `data.table` (took me 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has requested to tabulate the locations of patients by day even if they stay longer than one day at a particular location.

This requires to split up longer stays in chunks of one day at most. This can be accomplished by the `foverlaps()` function. For reshaping from wide to long format, the capability of `data.table::dcast()` to *reshape multiple columns simultaneously* is used.

```
library(data.table)
# coerce time columns to POSIXct
cols <- c("BeginTime", "EndTime")
setDT(data_bylocation2)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.POSIXct), .SDcols = cols]

# create sequence of days which cover the whole period
time_seq <- data_bylocation2[, seq(lubridate::floor_date(min(BeginTime), "day"),
                                   lubridate::ceiling_date(max(EndTime), "day"),
                                   by = "days")]
# chop longer stays into one day chunks
mDT <- foverlaps(data.table(Date = head(time_seq, -1L), end = tail(time_seq, -1L)),
                 setkey(data_bylocation2, BeginTime, EndTime), by.x = c("Date", "end"), nomatch = 0L)[
                   , (cols) := .(pmax(BeginTime, Date), pmin(EndTime, end))][
                     EndTime > BeginTime][
                     order(ID, Date, BeginTime)]

# reshape from long to wide form
val_cols <- c("BeginTime", "EndTime", "department", "room", "bed")
dcast(mDT, ID + Date ~ rowid(ID, Date), value.var = val_cols)[
  # reorder columns
  , setcolorder(.SD, c("ID", "Date", 
                       # create create column names in expected order using a cross join
                       mDT[, CJ(seq_len(max(rowid(ID, Date))), val_cols)[
                         , paste(V2, V1, sep = "_")]]))]
```

> ```
>          ID       Date         BeginTime_1           EndTime_1 bed_1 department_1 room_1         BeginTime_2  EndTime_2 bed_2 department_2 room_2
>  1: 2224003 2016-02-12 2016-02-12 08:00:00 2016-02-12 13:40:00     3         B12A    205 2016-02-12 13:40:00 2016-02-13     1         B12A    209
>  2: 2224003 2016-02-13 2016-02-13 00:00:00 2016-02-14 00:00:00     1         B12A    209                <NA>       <NA>    NA           NA     NA
>  3: 2224003 2016-02-14 2016-02-14 00:00:00 2016-02-15 00:00:00     1         B12A    209                <NA>       <NA>    NA           NA     NA
>  4: 2224003 2016-02-15 2016-02-15 00:00:00 2016-02-15 16:17:00     1         B12A    209                <NA>       <NA>    NA           NA     NA
>  5: 2248787 2016-04-20 2016-04-20 10:00:00 2016-04-21 00:00:00     2         B53A    306                <NA>       <NA>    NA           NA     NA
>  6: 2248787 2016-04-21 2016-04-21 00:00:00 2016-04-22 00:00:00     2         B53A    306                <NA>       <NA>    NA           NA     NA
>  7: 2248787 2016-04-22 2016-04-22 00:00:00 2016-04-23 00:00:00     2         B53A    306                <NA>       <NA>    NA           NA     NA
>  8: 2248787 2016-04-23 2016-04-23 00:00:00 2016-04-24 00:00:00     2         B53A    306                <NA>       <NA>    NA           NA     NA
>  9: 2248787 2016-04-24 2016-04-24 00:00:00 2016-04-24 11:47:00     2         B53A    306 2016-04-24 11:47:00 2016-04-25     4         B53A    311
> 10: 2248787 2016-04-25 2016-04-25 00:00:00 2016-04-26 00:00:00     4         B53A    311                <NA>       <NA>    NA           NA     NA
> 11: 2248787 2016-04-26 2016-04-26 00:00:00 2016-04-26 16:00:00     4         B53A    311                <NA>       <NA>    NA           NA     NA
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. The comments are also appreciated, so I can understand what's happening :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `tidyverse` and `lubridate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

data_bylocation %>%
  mutate(Date = date(BeginTime)) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -ID, -Date) %>%
  group_by(ID, Date, temp = variable) %>%
  mutate(index = row_number(),
         variable = paste0(variable, index)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-(temp:index)) %>%
  spread(variable, value) %>%
  select(ID, Date, c(6, 12, 9, 15, 3), c(6, 12, 9, 15, 3)+1, c(6, 12, 9, 15, 3)+2)
```

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
data = setDT(data_bylocation)

newDT = dcast(melt(data[, date := lubridate::date(BeginTime)],
                   id.vars = c("ID", "date"))[
                     ,.(variable2 = paste0(variable, 1:.N), value),
                     by = .(ID, date, variable)],
              ID + date ~ variable2, value.var = "value")

setcolorder(newDT, c(1:2, c(6, 12, 9, 15, 3), c(6, 12, 9, 15, 3)+1, c(6, 12, 9, 15, 3)+2))
```

**Result:**

```
        ID       Date                  BeginTime1                    EndTime1 department1 room1 Bed1
1  2156864 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 09:40:00.0000000 2016-03-02 15:20:00.0000000        L14B   102    3
2  2161034 2016-06-06 2016-06-06 09:00:00.0000000 2016-06-06 10:27:00.0000000        B51A   109    2
3  2161034 2016-06-07 2016-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 2016-06-07 11:02:00.0000000        B51A   109    2
4  2176442 2016-02-04 2016-02-04 07:15:00.0000000 2016-02-04 13:47:00.0000000        L14B   101    4
5  2176754 2016-03-15 2016-03-15 07:16:00.0000000 2016-03-15 14:56:00.0000000        B61A   109    3
6  2176754 2016-03-16 2016-03-16 08:10:00.0000000 2016-03-17 00:00:00.0000000        B61A   109    3
7  2176754 2016-03-17 2016-03-17 00:00:00.0000000 2016-03-17 11:18:00.0000000        B61A   109    3
8  2184060 2016-03-10 2016-03-10 20:25:00.0000000 2016-03-11 00:00:00.0000000        B61A   105    2
9  2184060 2016-03-11 2016-03-11 00:00:00.0000000 2016-03-12 00:00:00.0000000        B61A   105    2
10 2184060 2016-03-12 2016-03-12 00:00:00.0000000 2016-03-12 14:00:00.0000000        B61A   105    2
                    BeginTime2                    EndTime2 department2 room2 Bed2
1                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
2  2016-06-06 12:47:00.0000000 2016-06-07 00:00:00.0000000        B51A   109    2
3                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
4                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
5  2016-03-15 14:56:00.0000000 2016-03-16 08:10:00.0000000        B61A   109    2
6                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
7                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
8  2016-03-10 20:01:00.0000000 2016-03-10 20:25:00.0000000        B61A   105    1
9                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
10                        <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
                    BeginTime3                    EndTime3 department3 room3 Bed3
1                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
2  2016-06-06 10:27:00.0000000 2016-06-06 12:47:00.0000000        B51A   103    3
3                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
4                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
5                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
6                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
7                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
8                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
9                         <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
10                        <NA>                        <NA>        <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```

**Note:**

I'm still trying to think of a better way to rearrange the columns. This is the best I can get in the moment.

Comment: @FtD I see that you unaccepted my answer. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Thanks already, although I'm still a little stuck. A lot of the rows contain data from multiple dates (not in the example that I gave). And in these cases, the dates in between BeginTime and EndTime will not end up in the output. So my goal is to have a row for each day of the admission per patient, with its corresponding locations. Is there an easy way to do this? I posted another example in my question in which the problem occurs.

Comment: @FtD I don't understand, what do you mean by A lot of the rows contain data from multiple data? My solution works for the new example you just provided. Can you explain how it doesn't work?

Comment: I need a row for each day of the admission, with all locations for that day. So for instance for patient ID 2224003, there is no row for day 2016-02-13 or  2016-02-14. Furthermore, for patient ID 2248787 location dept B53A room 306 is only present in row 2016-04-23, although the patient also was here on the 24th (EndTime is 2016-04-24). Sorry for the misunderstanding, I now see that my question was not precise enough.